# Wolframscript output not evaluated

Tags: scripting

**Edit:** I made a stupid mistake, see answer below

Whenever I execute `wolframscript` code from the command line, my `Print[]` output doesn't get evaluated, however if I run the exact same file with the Mathematica front end it works fine. I can't work out why this might be happening, it doesn't seem to be a situation where `Evalute[]` helps.

Example:

```
M[a_, T_] := (4 \[Pi]^2 a^3)/(G T^2) /. {
        G -> Quantity["GravitationalConstant"]
}

(* Assuming inclined around major axis, no change to major axis *)
m1 = M[a, T] /. {
        T -> Quantity[15.7, "Years"],
        a -> 0.183 * 60^-2 * \[Pi]/180 * Quantity[7.9, "Kiloparsecs"]
} // UnitConvert;
Print["Assuming inclined around major axis: M = " <> ToString[m1, InputForm]]
m1S = UnitConvert[m1, "SolarMass"];
Print["\t = " <> ToString[m1S, InputForm]]
```

Gives me to following output on the command line, which isn't what I expect:

[image: command line output]

But when I run it in Mathematica it gives me exactly what I expect

[image]

`wolframscript --version` gives me `WolframScript 1.2.0 for MacOSX-x86-64`. Mathematica 11.3 is installed.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I would guess that the front end is using a Wolfram server to interpret the `Quantity` entities and that the kernel, which is what the script talks to, can't do that.

Comment: I am having trouble reproducing this, can you share any more details about which version of Mathematica you are using as well as `wolframscript --version`?  I don't think a front end is needed in this case.

Comment: @chuy Sure: WolframScript 1.2.0 for MacOSX-x86-64. The Mathematica front end is reports version 11.3

Comment: What do you see when you try `wolframscript -code 'Quantity[10,"pounds"]'`?

Comment: @chuy I get `Interpreting unit ....

Quantity[10, Pounds]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when I copied the file into the question above, I copied from the Mathematica front-end, which interprets the file contents slightly differently. The contents of the file is actually

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

M[a_, T_] := (4 π^2 a^3)/(G T^2) /. {
        G -> Quantity["GravitationalConstant"]
}

(* Assuming inclined around major axis, no change to major axis *)
m1 = M[a, T] /. {
        T -> Quantity[15.7, "Years"],
        a -> 0.183 * 60^-2 * π/180 * Quantity[7.9, "Kiloparsecs"]
} // UnitConvert;
Print["Assuming inclined around major axis: M = " <> ToString[m1, InputForm]]
m1S = UnitConvert[m1, "SolarMass"];
Print["\t = " <> ToString[m1S, InputForm]]
```

I had input π as a unicode symbol. Wolframscript didn't interpret this as the constant Pi, but when I open the file with the front-end it automatically converts any instance of π to `\[Pi]`. The command line input was therefore unable to evaluate the expression as it doesn't know what the symbol π is, and there also seems to be some encoding issues in the output.

Strangely the unicode input seems to work if I invoke the file with `wolframscript -script`, but not just with `wolframscript` or with `wolframscript -file`. (This seems to be discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174076/passing-utf-8-to-wolframscript-on-the-command-line).)

Sorry to waste anyone's time with an incorrect question.

Mea culpa!