# Passing UTF-8 to wolframscript on the command line

Tags: character-encoding, command-line, scripting

I am trying to use Unicode input to `wolframscript -c`, like so:

```
$ ./wolframscript -c '1/∞'
â^(-1)
```

The source of this behavior seems to be that `wolframscript` is failing to recognize multibyte characters and is instead interpreting the infinity symbol as its UTF-8 bytes (`â` is byte 226, and the others appear to be ignored).

```
$ ./wolframscript -c 'ToCharacterCode@"∞"'
{226, 136, 158}
```

Interestingly, it does seem to be able to handle UTF-8 from a file when called with `-script`, but *not* with `-f`:

```
$ echo '1/∞ // Print' > test
$ ./wolframscript -f test
â^(-1)
$ ./wolframscript -script test
0
```

Writing to a file and calling `wolframscript -script` on it is a solution, but I'd prefer to be able to specify the code as an argument.

`wolframscript -h` describes a `-charset CHARSET` argument that "Sets character output format," but I cannot seem to find an equivalent option for input encoding. The issue is present with both `urxvt` and `uxterm` on Arch Linux. My locale is `en_US.UTF-8`, but setting `LC_ALL=C` doesn't seem to change anything.

How can I make `wolframscript` recognize UTF-8 characters in code given as a command line argument?

Comment: I would report this to support@wolfram.com